# Setting TLS protocol for HTTPSURLConnection

Tags: java, security, http, ssl

I need to work against an F5 machine which uses TLS protocol connection.
For that I built a class which uses HTTPsURLConnection object.

```
m_httpsConnection = (HttpsURLConnection) m_url.openConnection();
```

Then, I downloaded the F5 certificate file, used the JDK keytool to create a keystore, and used it to try and set the connection to use TLS protocol:

```
        InputStream in = new FileInputStream(new File("c:/temp/F5keystore"));
        KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
        ks.load(in, "changeit".toCharArray());
        in.close();
        
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
        tmf.init(ks);
        X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager)tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, new TrustManager[] {defaultTrustManager}, null);
        SSLSocketFactory sslSocketFactory = context.getSocketFactory();
        
        ((HttpsURLConnection) m_httpsConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(sslSocketFactory);
```

(I spared the catches from you...)

The code seems to be passing fleuently, but when I do that:

```
OutputStream os = m_httpsConnection.getOutputStream();
```

I get...

"javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: **unable to find valid certification path to requested target**"

Now, I have the file F5keystore file under c:\temp, so why doesn't it find it?..

And is this really the correct way to set TLS to the connection? Right now I do it after opening the connection, although I might have thought it should be before the connection opening. But then, the connection is still null...

---

I am adding here more info following your requests:

```
C:\temp>keytool -v -printcert -file server.crt
Owner: EMAILADDRESS=root@localhost.localdomain, CN=localhost.localdomain, OU=MyOrg, O=MyCompany, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=--
Issuer: EMAILADDRESS=root@localhost.localdomain, CN=localhost.localdomain, OU=MyOrg, O=MyCompany, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=--

Serial number: 90f9d7e288ae6a77
Valid from: Fri Nov 07 08:20:36 IST 2014 until: Mon Nov 04 08:20:36 IST 2024
Certificate fingerprints:
         MD5:  C1:BE:43:9B:8B:C3:AA:F7:F2:BF:E6:06:08:42:18:17
         SHA1: 12:36:01:30:14:68:1C:C9:7D:7B:32:75:C6:08:86:E9:36:AD:CF:AA
         Signature algorithm name: SHA1withRSA
         Version: 3

Extensions:

#1: ObjectId: 2.5.29.14 Criticality=false
SubjectKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AA B6 71 94 D1 CB ED DF   1B 38 66 12 70 94 AA 76  ..q......8f.p..v
0010: 68 DF 2A 16                                        h.*.
]
]

#2: ObjectId: 2.5.29.19 Criticality=false
BasicConstraints:[
  CA:true
  PathLen:2147483647
]

#3: ObjectId: 2.5.29.35 Criticality=false
AuthorityKeyIdentifier [
KeyIdentifier [
0000: AA B6 71 94 D1 CB ED DF   1B 38 66 12 70 94 AA 76  ..q......8f.p..v
0010: 68 DF 2A 16                                        h.*.
]

[EMAILADDRESS=root@localhost.localdomain, CN=localhost.localdomain, OU=MyOrg, O=MyCompany, L=Seattle, ST=WA, C=--]
SerialNumber: [    90f9d7e2 88ae6a77]
]
```

Comment: can you add to post output from `openssl s_client -connect host:port` and `keytool -v -printcert -file path_to_cert_file` ?

Comment: Wow, it is too long for adding it as a comment, and I can't see other way to put it here... any suggestion? You know? I will try to edit the source question I posted...

Comment: Regarding the openssl, should I install it first? And the host:port refering to the F5, right?

Comment: You are using self-signed certificate for F5, so you should skip domain name validation. It can be done with calling (in pseudocode) `connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() { verify() {return true}})`

Comment: Thanks a lot. But I am having some difficulty to understand.. Is that correct? connection.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
    
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
     return true;
    }
});    And where is the correct place to put it?   When I put it right after setSSLSocketFactory line it didn't help...

Comment: Looks OK. Add it right after setSSLSocketFactory

Comment: Well, unfortunatley, no cure... Thanks you so much for your effort. Maybe somthing else?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71598/discussion-between-user1516873-and-dushkin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that actually I can bypass the certificate issue in order to continue with my activity. So I used [this](https://code.google.com/p/misc-utils/wiki/JavaHttpsUrl) to achieve this bypass.